# The most used probability distributions in moral hazard models?

Tags: microeconomics, probability, contract-theory

I'm engaged in making a variation of the canonical moral hazard model, but I need some examples of probability distributions to make some simulations and graphs. What are the probability distributions often used? I know that normal and uniform distributions do not work properly in this model. What else can I use?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You want to use distributions that satisfy the monotone likelihood ratio property. Some examples are given here: https://w.wiki/4C2b

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!